# Django Heroku Static Settings

Tags: python, django, heroku

I have a Django app that runs static files fine locally. When I push to Heroku, it's looking for static files in a different location (home/www_dev/www_dev/settings/static).

**File Structure:**

```
home
> www_dev
>>> organizations (my app)
>>> static
>>> www_dev
>>>>> settings
```

**base.py settings:** (used Two Scoops of Django template)

```
STATIC_ROOT = normpath(join(SITE_ROOT, 'assets'))
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    normpath(join(SITE_ROOT, 'static')),
)
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)
```

**production.py settings** (used Heroku documentation)

```
# Static asset configuration
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

**wsgi.py**

```
import os
from os.path import abspath, dirname
from sys import path

SITE_ROOT = dirname(dirname(abspath(__file__)))
path.append(SITE_ROOT)

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "www_dev.settings.production")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from dj_static import Cling

application = Cling(get_wsgi_application())
```

**Procfile**

```
web: gunicorn --pythonpath www_dev www_dev.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:$PORT
```

Tried adding to **urls.py** per other Stack Overflow posts, did not work:

```
if not settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        (r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.contrib.staticfiles.views.serve', {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),
    )
```

Heroku error:

```
-----> Preparing static assets
       Collectstatic configuration error. To debug, run:
       $ heroku run python ./www_dev/manage.py collectstatic --noinput
```

Result from running collectstatic:

```
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/app/www_dev/www_dev/settings/static'
```

I'm willing to just go to S3 if I can't solve this issue, but having trouble finding a good workflow for pushing static (CSS/JS) local to S3 with django-storages and boto. Would be find with having all media on S3. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `STATIC_ROOT` in your settings/production.py

If you don't need to use a different static root directory, you can simply delete the variable since it has been defined in the setting/base.py

The [heroku doc](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets#settings-py) assumes that you use a single settings.py file which locates in project_dir/settings.py.

Comment: That worked when I deleted all of the settings in production.py: deleted BASE_DIR, STATIC_ROOT, STATIC_URL, and STATICFILES_DIRS from Heroku's static asset configuration, since they were defined in base.py.